# Redux: Where should I place date formatting logic

Tags: redux

My question is simple, where should I put logic similar to date formatting?

Let's say I have a `Date` object that I'll eventually display as `01/02/2017` to the user. Where should I do the conversion from `Date` to `String`?

1. in `mapStateToProps` in the container component
2. in the presentational component, as part of the view rendering

My state (in the store) obviously should be stores as a `Date`, since I might need to present it with different formattings in other places, so I need to conversion from `Date` to `String`.

The advantage of `1` is that it makes the presentational component as dumb as possible.

The advantage of `2` is that the rendering logic stays in the presentational component.

I'm not sure where this type of logic belongs (another example would be money formatting from `Integer` to `String` adding `$` and `.00`).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, I could defend both options. I would normally use a selector that lives in a file next to my reducer (if you're using "ducks" or modules for example) so that even the `mapStateToProps` function is dumb.

However, if there's any chance that your container or some of its children will need to perform any calculation using that prop, then they will need the `Date` object,  not a string. Same with the number / money. If you need to summarize, aggregate or substract the quantity, the string won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to include this logic in componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method. So whenever you get new props date formatting logic will be executed and update local component's state variable which in turn will be rendered. Sample code is as below:

```
class ABC extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state= { dateVar: this.props.dataVar }
   }
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     //date formatting logic goes here
     this.setState({ dateVar: <formatted-date> })
   }
   render() {
      return(
        <div>{this.state.dateVar}</div>
      )
   }
```

}